# Why constructor executed only once in Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying to understand spring aop.I read this [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) . It says that constructor of an aspect runs twice, once for the original class object and other for the proxy object.But when I tried to make my own aspect with a public constructor, it executed only once.

Below is my code snippet:

```
package com.akash.aop;

public class TestAopBefore {

    public TestAopBefore() {
        System.out.println("TestAopBefore.TestAopBefore()");
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("TestAopBefore.getName()");
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("TestAopBefore.setName()");
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My Aspect Class

```
package com.akash.aop;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.akash.aop.TestAopBefore.get*())")
    public void runBeforeAllGetter() {
        System.out.println("MyAspect.runBeforeAllGetter()");
    }
}
```

My xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


    <bean id="testAopBefore" class="com.akash.aop.TestAopBefore" />
    <bean id="myAspect" class="com.akash.aop.MyAspect" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />

</beans>
```

My App class

```
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "myAop.xml");
        TestAopBefore testAopBefore = (TestAopBefore) context
                .getBean("testAopBefore");
        testAopBefore.setName("asd");
        testAopBefore.getName();
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

```
TestAopBefore.TestAopBefore()
TestAopBefore.setName()
MyAspect.runBeforeAllGetter()
TestAopBefore.getName()
```

Edit:

I am using a maven project and here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SpringDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resource</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>

    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have also added dependency for cglib but I think my code is not using it.

Comment: How are you compiling and running this? Is it possible that you're actually using full AspectJ rather than just Spring AOP? (Full AspectJ doesn't use proxies, so the passage that you link to doesn't apply to it.)

Comment: Hi @ruakh , I have edited the question and added the dependencies from which I am compiling my code.So How could I determine if I am using full aspectJ or not? And How to make it configure for Spring AOP ?

Comment: I'm actually not sure. Do you have any files named `aop.xml`?

Comment: No , there is only one xml file that is myAop.xml .

Comment: Are you sure you have CGLIB dependencies at class path ?

Comment: Spring AOP for beans creates proxies based on interfaces, so if there is no interface, it must fall back to CGLIB/AspectJ. Given that `TestAopBefore` is a class and not an interface, CGLIB compile-time weaving will be carried out.

Comment: @Babl I have added CGLIB dependency to my pom.xml but it doesn't make any difference if even I remove it. And that is where I cant understand.

Comment: I have added full pom.xml file with all other files.

Comment: @Steve cglib has nothing to do with compile time weaving, cglib means classbased proxies.

Comment: Which class type is your proxy? - I am not sure if this.getClass().getName() would give you a readable name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why do you need your constructor to be called twice but if you need explanation here it is.

Starting from Spring version 4.0 [DefaultAopProxyFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/DefaultAopProxyFactory.html) uses an [ObjenesisCglibAopProxy](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.1.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/aop/framework/ObjenesisCglibAopProxy.html) which is creating a proxy instance without invoking the default constructor on your classes. So if you want a double constructor behaviour you should downgrade to Spring 3.x or create your own AopProxyFactory implementation.

Cheers